# Import keywords into ace editor highlighter in webpy server (python)

Tags: javascript, python, syntax-highlighting, web.py, ace-editor

I am using the Javascript Ace text editor and need to load keywords into the (DynHighlightRules) to provide highlighting of the imported keywords. I have highlights working from static keywords in the

> editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/highlightRules")

, but I need to import new rules after the editor is rendered. I found a great solution which works perfectly in an Apache server but not in the Web.py python server. I believe this is due to the template page not being at the root level of the server. Has anyone deployed the Ace editor in Webpy and solved this issue?

Comment: If something works in Apache server but not in the python server, it must be caused by the way you set up your server. Try to tell more about that, otherwise this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: The python server has a base python page which calls the index.html page in a sub-folder called templates. As a result anything located in "templates" is one directory deeper than is the normal situation so all the relative pathing doesn't match the location it should. I'm not a fan of Web.py but I have to use it for this project. The sample code I found and got working in apache has the calls embedded in the html page thus causing the relative pathing issue. Code is located at http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/445/edit?html,output

Comment: you can use ace.config.set("basePath", "some/path") to change the place ace looks for files

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution to my problem. It's a work around and not the way I was originally going to solve the issue. My first attempts were to embed an ajax call in the "ace.define" function but it wouldn't process it correctly and parts would be missing causing errors. Then I tried to dynamically import the keywords but couldn't make that work in the python environment. Finally I thought to just wrap the whole thing in the success of the ajax call and now it works exactly right. I guess when embedded in the ace function the timing between the ajax events and the other parts of the definition were out of sync.

So the answer in short is to wrap the whole definition in the ajax success callback.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/readUserCreatedKeywords",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response){
                var keywordsString = "";
                var tmpArr = response.split(",");
                var tmpArrLen = tmpArr.length;
                var s = 0;
                var halfNum = 0;
                while (s < tmpArrLen) { // Clean array and save keywords and args into respective arrays
                    halfNum = parseInt(s/2);
                    tmpArr[s] = tmpArr[s].replace("u'", "").replace("[", "").replace("'", "").replace("(u", "").replace(")", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(" ", "");

                    if (s % 2 == 0){ //Store even values in keywords
                       keywordsString += tmpArr[s] + "|";
                       //console.log("tmpArr[" + s + "]" + tmpArr[s]);
                    }
                    s++;
                }

                ace.define("ace/mode/python_highlight_rules",["require","exports","module","ace/lib/oop","ace/mode/text_highlight_rules"], function(require, exports, module) {
                ...............................................lots of code..........................................

                exports.Mode = Mode;
                });

}
```

});